# What is the the minimum of a sequence of $n$ random variables having Gaussian distribution with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

If we have a sequence of $n$ random variables $[X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n]$, identically distributed having Gaussian distribution with zero mean and variance $\sigma^2$, then what is the lower bound of $\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\min}\{X_i \}$. For example, we know that $\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\max}\{X_i \} \leq \sigma \sqrt{2\log n}$, but I could not find anything on the minimum!!
Any help or reference to existing theory will be high appreciated!

Comment: you mean bounds on the *expected* max

Comment: $\min \{X_i\}=-\max \{-X_i\}$ . $(-X_i)$ is also i.i.d. $N(0,\sigma^{2})$.

Comment: So based on the identity $\min \{X_i\} = -\max\{ -X_i\}$ we get the lower bound as $\underset{1\leq i\leq n}{\min}\{X_i\}\geq -\sigma \sqrt{2\log n}$. Right?? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Yes, that is correct.